# How to improve performance of this python code

Tags: python, performance, loops, numpy, numba

I have a 28000x300 sized matrix called glove_vecs. The idea is to calculate loss for a row with all other rows and update them accordingly. Here's the function which does this.

```
@njit(nopython=True, fastmath=True)
def return_loss(length, cooccur, glove_vecs, bias, alpha, epochs):
    #Calculate Loss
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        total_loss = 0
        for i in range(length):
            for j in range(length):
                loss = dot(glove_vecs[i], glove_vecs[j]) + bias[i] + bias[j] - cooccur[i][j]
                mul, temp = alpha * loss, glove_vecs[j]
                glove_vecs[j] = element_wise_subtract(glove_vecs[j], mul, glove_vecs[i])
                glove_vecs[i] = element_wise_subtract(glove_vecs[i], mul, temp)
                bias[i], bias[j] = bias[i] - mul, bias[j] - mul
                total_loss+= 0.5 * (loss**2)
        print(total_loss, epoch)
    return glove_vecs
```

I am using numba and numpy. I found that writing my own dot product function gives a slight speed up over np.dot using numba. Same goes for the element wise subtraction.
Here are both those functions

```
@njit(nopython=True, fastmath=True)
def dot(v1, v2):
    out = 0
    for k in range(len(v1)):
        out+= v1[k] * v2[k]
    return out

@njit(nopython=True, fastmath=True)
def element_wise_subtract(v1, mul, v2):
    for k in range(len(v1)):
        v1[k]-= mul * v2[k]
    return v1
```

Currently, it takes nearly 12 minutes to run 1 epoch, that is the outer loop. I tried numba `parallel=True` mode with `prange` but it just worsened the performance while also giving wrong results.
Can the two inner for loops be avoided within the `return_loss` function? Or is there some other method to reduce the required time?

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding it, no iterations of your loss function depend upon previous frames? Is there a way to create a new thread to help divide the work?

Comment: The ith vector keeps updating every time the loss is calculated with a jth vector. So the new loss calculated depends on the previously updated ith vector and the current jth vector, so I think, it does depend upon previous frames.